# Let $u$ and $v$ be two linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Do they necessarily form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Stuck at that. Any tips/ hints/ solution at this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes.

One way to prove that is :

$Dim(\mathbb{R}^2)=2$ This is easy to check just using $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ as basis.

$u,v$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so $\operatorname{Span}(u,v)$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $u,v$ are basis of this space ( because definition of $\operatorname{Span}(u,v)$ are generators and they are linearly independent by hypothesis)

$Dim(\operatorname{Span}(u,v))=2$ and $\operatorname{Span}(u,v)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ so $\mathbb{R}^2=\operatorname{Span}(u,v)$ and $u,v$ is a basis.

Another way:

If $u,v$ do not form a basis is beacause they are not generators so $\exists w\in \mathbb{R}^2$ that is not in $\operatorname{Span}(u,v)$ so $w,u,v$ are $3$ independent vectors in  a 2-dimensional space what is a contradiction.

-Notation remarks:

$\operatorname{Span}(u,v)$ is the vector space generated by the set $\{u,v\}$ what means that :

$s\in \operatorname{Span}(u,v) \Leftrightarrow  \exists a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $s=au+bv$

Answer (score 0):

For a finite set of vectors to form a basis for $\mathbb{R^2}$ it must be linearly independent and span $\mathbb{R^2}$.

We already know that $\{\vec{u},\vec{v}\}$ is linearly independent.

Given an arbitrary vector $\vec{w}\in\mathbb{R^2}$ does there exist $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $a\vec{u}+b\vec{v}=\vec{w}$?

Say $\vec{u}=\langle x_0,y_0\rangle$ and $\vec{v}=\langle x_1,y_1 \rangle$ and $\vec{w}=\langle x_2,y_2 \rangle$,

then we have $\langle ax_0+bx_1,ay_0+by_1\rangle =\langle x_2,y_2 \rangle$ or

$$ax_0+bx_1=x_2$$
$$ay_0+by_1=y_2$$

and translated to matrix notation $A\vec{x}=\vec{w}$

$$\begin{pmatrix}x_0 & x_1 \\ y_0 & y_1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a\\ b\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x_2 \\ y_2\end{pmatrix}$$

note that the column vectors of $A$ are precisely $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, thus the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, and $A$ is invertible by the [Invertible Matrix Theorem](https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/invertible-matrix-thm.html), and we can solve for $\vec{x}=A^{-1}\vec{w}$, but $\vec{x}=\begin{pmatrix} a\\ b\end{pmatrix}$, thus we can always find $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $a\vec{u}+b\vec{v}=\vec{w}$ for arbitrary vector $\vec{w}\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Given $\vec{w}\in \mathbb{R}^2$, $\vec{w}\in\text{span}(\{\vec{u},\vec{v}\})$.

$\{\vec{u},\vec{v}\}$ is L.I. and spans $\mathbb{R}^2$, and is thus a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Other than that, I think a dimension argument would be nice as well. I just went step by step with the definition of a basis.

Answer (score 0):

Given a basis of $K^n$ ($K$ is the base field), $n$ vectors of $K^n$ are linearly independent if &  only if the determinant of their coordinates in the basis is nonzero.

Now, if the determinant  of these vectors is nonzero, we can compute express the vectors of the given basis as linear combinations of these vectors, by solving a system of $n$ linear equations with $n$ unknowns, and consequently these vectors span $K^n$ – in other words, as they're linearly independent, they make up a basis of $K^n$.